# Azure free account expired, but web test still active

Tags: azure, webtest

My Azure account (free subscription) is now expired. However, the web tests created to check the website availability (URL Ping test) is still active and can be seen in the web server logs. Too many requests are still getting fired. However, when I login to my azure portal, I only see subscription expired and no option to disable / remove the web test. How can I get web tests removed? Please suggest.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get access to your test you need to upgrade your account but if you only want to delete de data don´t worry because All the data will be deleted in 90 day. Maybe you already received an email from azure with this information.